# How to debug when using ARCore?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, debugging, arcore

I'm supposed to make a small AR app for android but since it seems ARCore can't use the computer's camera and Unity Remote isn't compatible with ARCore I have no way of running the app in the unity editor.

Only thing I can do right now is building the app, installing it on my phone, eventually create a canvas where I put some text to see if the app goes where I want it to go. I probably spent half the day debugging simple things because I can't find a way to have access to any console while using the app.

I can run a normal unity app with Unity Remote as long as ARCore isn't used, otherwise, it's just a black screen.

It's for a professional project so I can't just installed plenty of other plugins to make it work that way, I'm limited to ARCore and AR Foundation.

Comment: Not an answer, just a note -  your question is very good and it will be interesting to see the answers but at some point it may be easier to move to device testing anyway, as when working on real time sensitive tech like video, AR camera etc, testing on real devices is sometimes safer and avoids issues being masked or even caused by emulation and testing tools.